# How to reverse a shape in python?

Tags: python-3.x

I am hunter and I had a question out of interest for an upcoming exam. Basically I was wondering if there is a way to make and shape (triangle in this case) invert.

Below is my code. But I also have another code. Just wondering if there is an easier way than scraping and rewriting again.

```
def a(b):
    num = 1
    count= 0

    for i in range(0, b):
        row = ''

        for k in range(0, b-i):
            row = row + '      '
        count=count+2

        for j in range(1, count):
            if (num <10):
                row = row+'     '+str(num)
            if (num>9 and num<99):
                row = row+'    '+str(num)
            if (num==99):
                row = row+' '
            if (num>=99 and num<=1000):
                row = row+'   '+str(num)
            if (num>=1001 and num<=10000000):
                row = row+'  '+str(num)
            num = num +1
        print '\r'
        print(row)

b= input(str("number of rows:  "))

a(b)


def a(number):
    ctr = 1
    while(ctr <= number):
        row_spaces= ' ' * (number - ctr)
        row = (2*ctr-1) * '$'
        print(row_spaces+row)
        ctr = ctr +1

number= input(str("what is the amount of rows?  "))
a(number)
```

Answer (score 0):

To invert your triangle, you need to reverse your logic for spaces.Change your second while loop with the code below and it should work, I have done some modification in your code only:

```
def a(number):
    ctr = number
    while(ctr >= 1):
        row_spaces= ' ' * (number - ctr)
        row = (2*ctr-1) * '$'
        print(row_spaces+row)
        ctr = ctr -1

number= int(input("what is the amount of rows?  "))
a(number)
```

Output:

```
what is the amount of rows?  3
$$$$$
 $$$
  $
```

Comment: Thank you! I actually wrote the second; the first being an example from class. I am trying to reverse logic on the first and can't quite seem to get it going. I get it to print only one other way and that is just a left line down in a regular triangle. I thought there may have been a simple flip code.

Comment: Sorry btw for the long post; first time user and very basic understanding in all thinks python!:)

Answer (score 0):

```
def a(b):
b = int(b)
num = b*b -1
count = b*2

for i in range(0, b):
    row = ''

    for k in range(0, i):
        row = row + '      '

    num = num - (count-3)

    for j in range(1, count):
        if (num <10):
            row = row+'     '+str(num)
        if (num>9 and num<99):
            row = row+'    '+str(num)
        if (num==99):
            row = row+' '
        if (num>=99 and num<=1000):
            row = row+'   '+str(num)
        if (num>=1001 and num<=10000000):
            row = row+'  '+str(num)
        num = num +1

    num = num - 1 -(count)
    count = count-2

    print '\r'
    print(row)

b= input("number of rows:  ")
a(b)
```